# How to configure Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: configuration-wizard

I am working on a class group project in which we have to install and configure sharepoint. I installed a Sharepoint server 2010 in the windows server 2008 R2 as a standalone server. I am connected with the domain. Now i don't what I have to configure next. I have never used Sharepoint before. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Pete,

Installation of SharePoint can be as simple or as complex as you want.

The easy and simple way is:

1. Install the pre-requisites
2. Install the SharePoint binaries
3. Run the products and technologies configuration wizard from the start menu or by choosing to do so at the end of the SharePoint setup
4. Run the farm configuration wizard in the central administration, which is opened in the browser after the previous wizard completes.

After this you're good to go.